# Making certain templates only show for certain authors

Tags: templates

Want to know how to make sure a template only gets used when we want it

Our main article template for our columns runs ads

I need a template that has no ads for one of our authors.  How do I ensure there is no bleeding of content onto the wrong template

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a conditional to display, or not display the ads. So if the content author is anyone but the said author, show ads. If it is them, it won't show the ads:

`{if author_id != "xx"}
  < Ad Code Here >
{/if}`

Just put the author's id in place of the "xx".

Comment: And/or use different group and use group_id instead of author_id.

Comment: will the conditional work for the template    {if author_id != "xx"} use a template

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify that? Do you mean the ad code is coming in from an embed? If so, yes, it should work.

And Benoit L's suggestion about a different group is good if there could ever be more than just this one author with this restriction.

Comment: it is nothing about ads.  our regular template has ads, they want a template without ads.  I can do this. but in the past i noticed that there is nothing stopping  the system from assigning the ads free template to the regular template.  I use to run specialiaty templates for health, automotive and travel pages.  I would get auto  pages on travel templates showing up in google

Comment: You're losing me and over-complicating this. You have an answer how to use your existing templates, and have ads not show when a specific author's content is shown. That was the question you asked. It was answered. Please mark it as such.

If you have another question about whatever template issues you are having, then start a new question rather than piggy-back on this one.